# R Shiny Reactively / Dynamically Assign an Object Name

Tags: r, shiny, assign

How can I create reactive objects names and assign values / data to them in Shiny. I am reading a (configuration) file that provides me the object names and assign's the values / data to each object. This is what I would do if I were not using Shiny:

```
  df = data.frame(Object_Name = c("Test", "Dummy"), 
                  Value = c("3*2", "mtcars"))
  
  for (i in 1:length(df$Object_Name)) {
    
    assign(x = df$Object_Name[i], 
           value = eval(parse(text = df$Value[i])), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    
  }
```

In Shiny, if I were to write the below code then it will work, but this is manual and not configurable / dynamic:

```
library(shiny)

df = data.frame(Object_Name = c("Test", "Dummy"), 
                Value = c("3*2", "mtcars"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  assign(x = "Dummy", 
         value = reactive({ eval(parse(text = "mtcars")) }), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  output$test = renderTable({ Dummy() })
  
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is it possible to loop through the assign function and dynamically assign object names, or is the only way to do that through reactiveValues?

Comment: This feels like a very weird way to use reactive values. Would a `reactiveValues()` list not be easier to work with? Maybe it would be better to talk about the problem you are really trying to solve rather than trying to adjust how you've attempted to solve it. There may be better ways.

Comment: @MrFlick I have a configuration file with multiple tabs. Tab 1 for example is a tab that gives instructions on how to create an object and its corresponding object name. Tab 2 takes that object name and passes it to functions to create visuals. If I use reactiveValues, it will inherently change the object name that is in Tab 2.

Comment: So it sounds like the real problem is that these functions only allow you to set values of the visualizations using the object name.  Are these functions ones that you've written? Because most base R plotting functions or ggplot functions don't require that. It would be best to avoid such awkward requirements to make it easier to use in other situations.

Comment: So it isn't a limitation of the function, it is a limitation of the configuration file. For example, my functions are pretty standard as they take in parameters, and use those parameters to carry out the calculations, etc in the function. However, the configuration file passes specific object names to the parameters in the functions that I created. So if the configuration file says pass object name "Data.Test" as the "x" parameter in function myFunc(x = ), then I need to create an object with name "Data.Test", as the config file will evaluate myFunc(x = Data.Test).